# How to force garbage collection in Moscow ML

Tags: garbage-collection, sml, mosml

Is there a way to force garbage collection in mosml? I am looking for something similar to SML/NJ's `SMLofNJ.Internals.GC.doGC` and MLton's `MLton.GC.collect`. Is it possible in Moscow ML?

Version: mosml 2.10.1